# Delete first two lines and add two lines to file

Tags: ruby, file, read-write

I have a text file that starts with:

```
Title

aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I don't know what the line would include, but I know that the structure of the file will be `Title`, then an empty line, then the actual lines. I want to modify it to:

```
New Title

fff
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I had [this](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/File.writelines) in mind:

```
lineArray = File.readlines(destinationFile).drop(2)
lineArray.insert(0, 'fff\n')
lineArray.insert(0, '\n')
lineArray.insert(0, 'new Title\n')
File.writelines(destinationFile, lineArray)
```

but `writelines` doesn't exist.

```
`writelines' for File:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Is there a way to delete the first two lines of the file an add three new lines?

Comment: You linked to the documentation for the Facets gem. If you want to use `File.writelines` you'll have to install that gem.

Comment: @Jordan Is there a built in way to do this in ruby without a third party gem?

Comment: P.S. The title of your question says "first two lines" but it sure looks like you want to replace the first three (a blank line is still a line). FWIW, an easier way to replace the first three items in an array is `lineArr[0..2] = [ "New Title\n", "\n", "fff\n" ]`

Comment: Click on the "View source" link at the bottom of the Facets docs. It's only a four-line method. That's how you do it in Ruby.

Comment: How big will your file be? Will it ever grow? Using `readlines` or any other IO method that slurps the file will be unscalable.

Comment: @theTinMan it will grow continually, I cant say how big it is going to be exactly but assuming after a year it might be anywhere from 5k to 20k lines

Comment: Be cautious using slurping: It can take a script to its knees if the file exceeds the available memory for the process. It's easier to write the code using slurping though, so it's important to be aware of the problem. Also, slurping slows the IO once the file gets larger than 1MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with something like this:

```
NEWLINES = {
  0 => "New Title",
  1 => "\nfff"
}

File.open('test.txt.new', 'w') do |fo|
  File.foreach('test.txt').with_index do |li, ln|
    fo.puts (NEWLINES[ln] || li)
  end
end
```

Here's the contents of `test.txt.new` after running:

```
New Title

fff
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

The idea is to provide a list of replacement lines in the `NEWLINES` hash. As each line is read from the original file the line number is checked in the hash, and if the line exists then the corresponding value is used, otherwise the original line is used.

If you want to read the entire file then substitute, it reduces the code a little, but the code will have scalability issues:

```
NEWLINES = [
  "New Title",
  "",
  "fff"
]

file = File.readlines('test.txt')
File.open('test.txt.new', 'w') do |fo|
  fo.puts NEWLINES
  fo.puts file[(NEWLINES.size - 1) .. -1]
end
```

It's not very smart but it'll work for simple replacements.

If you really want to do it right, learn how [`diff`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) works, create a diff file, then let it do the heavy lifting, as it's designed for this sort of task, runs extremely fast, and is used millions of times every day on *nix systems around the world.

Comment: Good point about `diff`. You might want to show how that could be done from within Ruby.

Comment: I thought of that, but it's a very different question.

Answer (score 1):

Use put with the whole array:

```
File.open("destinationFile", "w+") do |f|
   f.puts(lineArray)
end
```

Comment: will this write into the file line by line? If so wouldn't be this bad practice for big files?

Comment: This should be fast enough as there is no way to write array to file with out going all over the array...

Comment: I believe the OP wants a way to delete the first 2 lines of the file and then insert 3 new lines at the beginning **without** reading in the entire file and then writing out the entire file, which I think is impossible with Ruby's `File` methods.

Comment: So why to use lineArray = File.readlines(destinationFile).drop(2)... @u.gen? Please elaborate...

Comment: Pretty sure the OP is confused about what `File.readlines(destinationFile).drop(2)` does. I think he believes that is removing the first 2 lines of the file and return them, which is wrong. It is only returning them, does not remove them.

Comment: there is no specific reason, first time trying out ruby and I thought my solution would work.  My approach might not be a good approach, If the file is big reading&writing each line would be a problem in long term. So I'd like to see the best approach to this problem.

Comment: Why use `w+` instead of the usual `w`? Explain the reasoning in the answer.

Comment: @Mike so I thought `drop` is omitting first two lines and returning rest of the lines into the array? Am I wrong ?

Comment: "w+" Overwrites the existing file if the file exists.

Comment: There is no way to write text data in the middle of a file. Not just in ruby - this is just how the file system works.

Comment: `w` overwrites the file if it exists. `w+` is `"*Read-*write, truncates existing file to zero length or creates a new file for reading and writing."` They're not the same. Don't use `w+` when you mean `w` as it can cause problems when multiple files are trying to access the file at the same time.

Comment: @u.gen you have the order backwards, it's **not** "omitting the first two" and **then** "returning the rest of the lines into the array". It is **first** returning all the lines into an array, **then** omitting the first two from the array. The order matters because it's not actually editing the file.

Comment: I think "w+" is what the OP need in this case as i understand it. And the OP now has all the information to select what is relevant for his case...

Answer (score 1):

If your files are big, the performance and memory implications of reading them into memory in their entirety are worth thinking about. If that's a concern, then your best bet is to treat the files as streams. Here's how I would do it.

First, define your replacement text:

```
require "stringio"

replacement = StringOI.new <<END
New Title

fff
END
```

I've made this a [StringIO](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) object, but it could also be a File object if your replacement text is in a file.

Now, open your destination file (a new file) and write each line from the replacement text into it.

```
dest = File.open(dest_fn, 'wb') do |dest|
replacement.each_line {|ln| dest << ln }
```

We could have done this more efficiently, but there's a good reason to do it this way: Now we can call `replacement.lineno` to get the number of lines read, instead of iterating over it a second time to count the lines.

Next, open the original file and seek ahead by calling `gets` `replacement.lineno` times:

```
orig = File.open(orig_fn, 'r')
replacement.lineno.times { orig.gets }
```

Finally, write the remaining lines from the original file to the new file. We'll do it more efficiently this time with [`File.copy_stream`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-copy_stream):

```
File.copy_stream(orig, dest)
orig.close
dest.close
```

That's it. Of course, it's a drag closing those files manually (and when we do we should do it in an `ensure` block), so it's better to use the block form of `File.open` to automatically close them. Also, we can move the `orig.gets` calls into the `replacement.each_line` loop:

```
File.open(dest_fn, 'wb') do |dest|
  File.open(orig_fn, 'r') do |orig|
    replacement.each_line {|ln| dest << ln; orig.gets }
    File.copy_stream(orig, dest)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First create an input test file.

```
FNameIn = "test_in"

text = <<_
Title

How now,
brown cow?
_
  #=> "Title\n\nHow now,\nbrown cow?\n" 

File.write(FNameIn, text)
  #=> 27
```

Now read and write line-by-line.

```
FNameOut = "test_out"

File.open(FNameIn) do |fin|
  fin.gets; fin.gets  
  File.open(FNameOut, 'w') do |fout|
    fout.puts "New Title"
    fout.puts
    fout.puts "fff"
    until fin.eof?    
      fout.puts fin.gets
    end
  end
end
```

Check the result:

```
puts File.read(FNameOut)
  # New Title
  #
  # fff
  # How now,
  # brown cow?
```

Ruby will close each of the two files when its block terminates.

If the files are not large, you could instead write:

```
File.write(FNameOut,
  ["New Title\n", "\n", "fff\n"].concat(File.readlines(FNameIn).drop(2)).join)
```